# Which version of Ubuntu for JDK 7?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm running through a installation guide that requires Ubuntu and JDK7. I know the latest version of Ubuntu (16.04) installs the current JDK8 via apt-get.

What is the latest version of Ubuntu that will install JDK7 via apt-get?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [packages list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/java/) it shows that [openjdk-7-jdk](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/java/openjdk-7-jdk) is available by default through `apt-get` in Ubuntu 15.10 (wily).

You can also install Oracle Java 7 via [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16263651/1771479):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Also see:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java
- [Installing Java 7 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu)